# Typo3 tx_news eventnews: location_simple and organizer_simple

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have no luck showing the contents of the fields location_simple or organizer_simple in list or detail view.
If there is a seperate location it can be shown with {newsItem.location.title} but if only the loction simple field is filled out i can't get it to show up.
I tried the following:
{newsItem.location_simple}
{newsItem.location.location_simple}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{newsItem.locationSimple}` as every `_` is transformed into uppercase.